# Why difference in behavior with Set<Objects> and Map<Object,Object>

Tags: java, data-structures

```
Line 1 :      Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
Line 2 :      singletons.add(new Integer(2));
Line 3 :      Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Why compiler complains at line 3 and doesn't complains at line 2?

Comment: Where do you see a difference in behaviour between maps and sets? You're not doing the same thing in both cases at all. `Integer` is implicitly convertible to `Object`. `HashMap<String, String>` isn't implicitly convertible to `Map<String, Object>`.

Comment: Generics work differently. If you changed the first line to `new HashSet<String>()` there would be an error too.

Comment: @Jon Integer implicitly convertible to object then why Map<String,String> can't be converted to Map<String, Object> ? after all String is also Object only. What's compiler trying to save us from by raising the error ? and why that would not be a problem with Set<Object> ?

Comment: @Manish: It *would* be a problem with `Set<Object>` - try using `Set<Object> set = new HashSet<String>();` and you'll see the problem. And while `Integer` is a subtype of `Object`, `Map<String, String>` isn't a subtype of `Map<String, Object>`. You can put non-string values into a `Map<String, Object>` for example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31222214/why-difference-in-behavior-with-setobjects-and-mapobject-object#comment50444375_31222214), if you change your first line to

```
Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<String>();
```

you'll get the same error.  This is because `HashSet<String>` (and even `Set<String>`) is not a subtype of `Set<Object>`.  To see why, think about the operations you'll call on that collection. You've already made one call to add an `Integer` object to it.

```
singletons.add(new Integer(2));
```

That works fine because you instantiated `singletons` to be `HashSet<Object>`. If you had instantiated it as a `HashSet<String>`, then you'd be adding an `Integer` object to a `String` collection, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Try either

```
 Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

or

```
 Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

but I would use the diamond operator on the right, if you use java version >= 7

```
 Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```